# Is it possible to transfer my New Leaf town from 2DS to 2DSXL with no system transfer?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl

I have the digital copy of *Animal Crossing: New Leaf* on my old 2DS and I got a new 2DS XL - it's the New Leaf edition so it comes with New Leaf preinstalled.
I transferred my system data from my 3DSXL to my new 2DS XL and completely forgot about my 2DS, so when I went back to play New Leaf I *completely* forgot that my New Leaf town was on my 2DS, not on my 3DS XL.

I'm frustrated and wondering if there's any way I can transfer the save from my 2DS to my 2DS XL - literally any way at all, I'm open to no matter how difficult.